# Updating a record with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to update a record with an admin user with a "validate" button that changes the record's status from pending to confirmed. I've created a form, and the route to do so, however the controller is giving me trouble, I'm not sure what to code for it to update the specific record i click validate for.

Hours controller

```
def index
    @allhours = HourLog.where(status:'Pending')
  end
def update
    @hour = HourLog.where(status:'Pending')
    @hour.update(@hour.id, :status)
  end
```

Hours/index.html.erb

```
<td><%=form_for(:hour_log, method: :put) do |f|%>
    <%= f.hidden_field :status, :value => 'Confirmed' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Validate'%>
    <%end%>
</td>
```

Any help would be fantastic, thanks!

error:
NoMethodError in HoursController#update
undefined method `id' for #

I know something is wrond with the (@hour.id) section of the controller in the update def, but I don't know what to replace it with

edit: rake routes

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
           root GET    /                          welcome#index
         signup GET    /signup(.:format)          users#new
          users GET    /users(.:format)           users#index
                POST   /users(.:format)           users#create
       new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)       users#new
      edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)  users#edit
           user GET    /users/:id(.:format)       users#show
                PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)       users#update
                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)       users#destroy
                GET    /users(.:format)           users#index
                PUT    /users(.:format)           users#update
          login GET    /login(.:format)           sessions#new
                POST   /login(.:format)           sessions#create
         logout DELETE /logout(.:format)          sessions#destroy
      dashboard GET    /dashboard(.:format)       hours#new
dashboard_hours GET    /dashboard/hours(.:format) hours#index
          hours PUT    /hours(.:format)           hours#update
                GET    /hours(.:format)           hours#index
                POST   /hours(.:format)           hours#create
       new_hour GET    /hours/new(.:format)       hours#new
      edit_hour GET    /hours/:id/edit(.:format)  hours#edit
           hour GET    /hours/:id(.:format)       hours#show
                PATCH  /hours/:id(.:format)       hours#update
                PUT    /hours/:id(.:format)       hours#update
                DELETE /hours/:id(.:format)       hours#destroy
```

hours Controller

```
class HoursController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_user
  before_action :require_admin, only: [:index]
  def index
    @allhours = HourLog.where(status:'pending')
  end
  def new
    @hour = current_user.hour_logs.new
    @entry = current_user.hour_logs.all
  end
  def edit
    flash[:warning] =  "Hash: #{params}"
  end

  def create
    @hour = HourLog.new(hour_params)
    @hour.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    @hour.status = 'pending'
    if @hour.save
      redirect_to '/dashboard'
    end
  end
  private
  def hour_params
    params.require(:hour_log).permit(:assignment, :hours, :supervisor, :date)
  end
  def update_hour_params
    params.require(:hour_log).permit(:status)
  end
end
```

HourLog method

```
class HourLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: "however the controller is giving me trouble." What does this even mean? What is the EXACT problem you're seeing?

Comment: it is not updating the record because of the "id" i enter. If i enter (params[:id], :status), then it says it cannot find a record without an id. now it's saying that ".id" is an undefined method

Comment: @DKucher please post the full error message _in the question body_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this has an answer accepted, but I'd like to propose an alternative solution for anyone who may come along and find this question. Assumptions: The base page is an index with all pending items and the click is a simple state change. (A state toggle could be easily added to this solution.)

(I'm using the naming from the question.)

### **Using link_to as a message**

A state change from 'Pending' to 'Confirmed' for a flag could be  implemented by using the link_to to trigger the controller action to update this flag. **Hash params may be passed via a link_to enabling simplified logic in the controller.**

**VIEW: Index.html.erb**

```
<% @allhours.each do |hour| %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= hour.textdescriptionvar %> is an item pending approval. 
        <%= link_to(" Click to approve", edit_hour_path(hour, :status => "Confirmed"))
    </li>
  </ul>

<% end %>
```

**CONTROLLER: HourLogsController**

```
       def edit
            flash[:info] =  "Hash: #{params}"
            @hour = HourLog.find(params[:id])
        end

        def update
            @hour = HourLog.find(params[:id])
            @hour.update_attributes(hours_params)
            if  @hour.save
               redirect_to @hour, :notice => "Successfully changed stat."
            else
                render 'index' # Any action here, index for example
            end
          end
    private

        def hours_params
          params.require(:hour_log).permit(:status)           
        end
```

*I would recommend a data: confirm message be added to the link_to,but I wanted to mimic the poster's situation as posted.*

Rails spec for link_to [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Comment: Sure. I just used a generic path. You need to look up the url in your raked routes and find the edit pathfor hour_log. If you want  some help with this, please post the output of your $rake routes

Comment: Cool. Updated the answer with your URL, which is edit_hour_path(...). Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I used hour_log, since that was the model name on your form you posted. It should be the lower case name for the model where you define < ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: I use hour_log in a different param, which is working. but this doesn't seem to work

Comment: We need to find out what the variable name is inside the params{} hash. That's the name that needs to be inside that method.

Comment: it does not flash the params, only goes to the edit page

Comment: I went ahead and updated the controller code to completion with redirect on successful save, and unsuccessful save, etc. This is working code. Since you are the one with access to all your code, only you can set the variable names correctly. Displaying the params hash in the controller is critical for tracking parameters between views and the controller. Play with that and see if you can get that working; it will help you in the future for sure.

Comment: My problem is that it updates the first record in the databse, because there is a find_by method, which returns one record, the top record. any way to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for posting the controller code. There is more than one problem here. Your controller method doesn't resemble the answer. Specifically, it doesn't have an update action at all, so that's a problem. In addition, it looks like you need 2 different edits, one for the status, and a separate one for the rest of the record. This is okay, but then you need a set of corresponding actions:, 2 edit actions, 2 update actions, or logic to select edit/update for a given case. Maybe look at this tutorial https://www.railstutorial.org/, it has good information about structuring controllers.

Comment: I still don't know how to make the button link to the certain record. that's the only issue i have

Comment: @hour = HourLog.new(hour_params) is not correct.  Various other problems in the controller need to be addressed..As far as the question I was answering initially, the link_to represents the entire context, the controller, action, and record id which needs to be queried from the database. In Rails, the var info is communicated in the params[] hash. The .find creates the query to GET the record based on the :id (from the hash) you pass it. Your debug needs to start at looking at the point the link_to message enters the controller. I wish you the best. It takes time to learn Rails for everyone.

Comment: In your controller create action => @hour = HourLog.new(hour_params) -- this is not correct. I was pointing out one of the errors that has nothing to do with the original question but that indicates the controller overall needs work. I have to exit this conversation. I've given all the advice I have to give. You need to debug your controller -- start with the params hash. I do wish you luck.

Answer (score 1):

`@hour = HourLog.where(status:'Pending')` will return an ActiveRecord Relation, not a single record.

Try this:

```
@hour = HourLog.find_by(status: 'pending')
@hour.update_attribute :status, params[:hour_log][:status]
```

This method finds the first record with status ="pending" and updates that instead of the specific record.

Comment: I tried, and got this error: NoMethodError in HoursController#update
undefined method `update_attribute' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Oh, well that implies that there is no HourLog with a `status` of `pending`.

Comment: But i have a view that shows the status of the HourLog entries, and it still shows pending. I think "update_attribute" is the problem. any way to use a different method?

Comment: Nope, if it says `undefined method 'update_attribute' for nil` then it's telling you that it tried to call `update_attribute` on `nil`, which means `@hour` is `nil`, which means `HourLog.find_by(status: 'pending')` is returning `nil`, which means it can't find anything with that status.  You could compare that to `HourLog.where(status: 'pending').count` and you'll see that it's `0`.

Comment: You're right, there was just a capitalization issue with "Pending". Now I'm getting a template error: Missing template hours/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/DK/desktop/project/nhs/app/views" * "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-3.2.0/app/views"

Comment: Yup! :)  Now I think you'll want to redirect the user to another page with a flash message telling them of the success.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want `@hour.update params[:hour_log]` instead because `update_attribute` doesn't run validations.  and keep data in your database lowercase unless it's something written by a user.  this link is useful http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/